# Ideas on cooling a reflowed graphics chipset on HP DV series

Tags: bios, exchange, cooling, editing

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to replace the bios on either the chipset for the video card or the bios to increase the cooling dynamics.

Comment: Please [edit] your wall of text and remove everything that is not relevant to your actual question.

Comment: As your questions stands, it's a bit hard to read because it's all lumped in a single paragraph. Please edit your question to break it into several paragraphs and remove text that isn't relevant to the issue you're trying to address.

Comment: any particular model of DV?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want improve cooling? Have you found out the temperatures of hardware components? Changing BIOS won't cool anything; cooling is done by heat sinks, fans and thermal grease.